# Controlling my keyboard's RGB LEDs under Linux

Tags: keyboard

So, I bought a [Skiller Mech SGK3](https://sharkoon.com/product/SKILLER+MECH+SGK3) mechanical keyboard. It works perfectly under Linux, but under Windows I can use its software to configure the RGB LED lighting patterns and macros.

How would I do the same under Linux? Running its software under Wine doesn't work, of course, since it expects direct hardware access.

Comment: Assuming an USB connection: (1) Capture the USB packets with one of the many Windows USB sniffers when you run the configuration rools under Windows; reverse engineer the format. (2) Look at the HID descriptor of the keyboard under Linux; if it contains hints to the necessary commands, play around with it and see how the keyboard reacts. (3) Write an open source tool for the results of (1) and (2) and share it (or google, possibly someone has already written such a tool). (1) and (2) require you to read up on USB, HID, etc. pp, and will need a bit of effort.

Comment: @dirkt: This was an answer!

Comment: @sshine Well, for an actual answer someone with the hardware would need to do this, and then write up the needed commands, so the next person can also use them without having to do the reverse engineering.